# Is it possible to run bootstrap for rebar3 offline?

Tags: erlang, rebar3

Does it possible to run bootstrap command offline for rebar3. Where do I keep the dependency packages(cf, erlware_commons,getopt, providers).

I get below error when I run `./bootstrap` offline.

```
| Error: Unable to fetch package providers 1.8.1: failed connect
| Error: Unable to fetch package getopt 1.0.1: failed connect
| Error: Unable to fetch package cf 0.3.1: failed connect
| Error: Unable to fetch package erlware_commons 1.4.0: failed connect
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented way to do it, but it appears to be possible to place the dependencies under `_build/default/lib` before running the bootstrap script. You also need the dependencies of the dependencies, exactly which can be figured out by running the bootstrap script when online. (Tested with version 3.17.0 and the deps were bbmustache,  certifi,  cf,  cth_readable,  erlware_commons,  eunit_formatters,  getopt,  providers,  relx,  ssl_verify_fun.)

I have created an issue to create an official way to do it: https://github.com/erlang/rebar3/issues/2640.